# How to bulkify invocable method that receives a list of leads

Tags: apex, invocable-method

```
    @InvocableMethod(label='lead Round Robin' description='Round robin lead assignment' category='Lead')
    public static void AssignLeads(List<ID> ids) {
        Lead l = [Select Id, Business_Line__c From Lead Where Id =: ids[0]];
        List<Lead_Assignments__c> la = [Select Id, Business_Development_Rep__c From Lead_Assignments__c Where Assignment_Type__c = 'Round Robin' AND Active__c = true ORDER BY Last_Lead_Assign_Date_Time__c ASC Limit 1];
        
        
        If(la != null){
            
            l.OwnerId = la.Business_Development_Rep__c;
            l.Last_Lead_Assign_Date_Time__c = DateTime.now();
            
            la.Last_Lead_Assign_Date_Time__c = DateTime.now();
            
            update l;
            update la;
            
        }
```

Above code works fine when receiving one Id in, I cannot figure out how to properly bulkify it. I know I would need to switch Lead l to a list and 'Where Id=: ids[0]' to 'Where Id in :ids' but im having trouble with the lead assignments portion and tying them to leads without querying in a for loop.

Comment: Invocable methods receive arrays BECAUSE of bulkification. Each actual call from the flow contributes one entry in the list. So if you expect to receive a list from the flow you actually need to accept a list of lists. You then need to process them together, to address bulkification, then return one entry per item in the input list... the last being unnecessary when the return type is void, of course.

Answer (score 0):

One bulkifies invocable apex similar to triggers by using Maps

```
@InvocableMethod(label='lead Round Robin' description='Round robin lead assignment' category='Lead')
public static void AssignLeads(List<ID> ids) {
   
    Map<Id,Lead> leadsById = new Map<Id,Lead> (
       [SELECT Id, Business_Line__c 
         FROM Lead WHERE Id =: ids];
    List<Lead_Assignments__c> la = [SELECT Id, Business_Development_Rep__c 
         FROM Lead_Assignments__c 
         WHERE Assignment_Type__c = 'Round Robin' AND Active__c = true
         ORDER BY Last_Lead_Assign_Date_Time__c ASC Limit 1];
    
    if (la == null) {throw someException}
    for (Lead l : leadsById.values() ) {
        l.OwnerId = la.Business_Development_Rep__c;
        l.Last_Lead_Assign_Date_Time__c = System.now();
    }
    update leadsById.values();
    update new Lead_Assignments__c (Id = la.Id,
                                    Last_Lead_Assign_Date_Time__c = System.now);
```

**Notes:**

1. Do the update outside of the for loop
2. Note use of map constructor that takes a list of sobjects